# Android: Is there a way to manipulate battery level display on the battery indicator programatically

Tags: android, android-intent, batterylevel

I have gone through some of the questions in the stackoverflow and checked Android developer documents as well to understand whether is it possible to change battery level displayed programatically.

Everywhere everyone talks about reading the battery level (which i have already worked on)

Can someone please point me at some document or give some code to modify the battery level on  the device.

Comment: This is not possible from the Android SDK. I am going to assume that you are aware of this and are looking to make alterations to the Android source code for your own ROM mod.

Comment: @DileepMettu: Where you able to resolve your issue.If yes,then pls share

Comment: @Basher51: Sorry, I was trying a POC on the same and didn't go forward due to its complexity!!